# es6 call extended component function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Ok so what I'm trying to do is :

I'm extending react-photo-gallery component and it has this openLightbox function, and I want to do something else in my component when that function is triggered, I tried something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl';
import Gallery from 'react-photo-gallery';

export class GaleryComponent extends Gallery {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.openLightBox = this.openLightBox.bind(this);

  }
  openLightbox() {
    console.log("LIGHTBOX OPENED");
  }
}
```

What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: WTH is `this.openLightbox = super.openLightbox` supposed to do? That overrrides the overwritten method with the orginal one.

Answer (score 3):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl';
import Gallery from 'react-photo-gallery';

export class GaleryComponent extends Gallery {

  constructor(props) {
    // No need to set this.openLightbox, it will be available from the prototype chain
    super(props);
  }

  // If you want to override openLightbox, you can use super and add your own code
  openLightbox() {
    super.openLightbox();
    console.log("LIGHTBOX OPENED");
  }


  // Had you not overridden it, you would be accessing the super's openLightbox
  componentDidMount() {
      this.openLightbox();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, tried the same and still getting nothing, here is the lib, https://github.com/neptunian/react-photo-gallery/blob/master/src/Gallery.js I'm really not sure why it's not working

Comment: @MarkuzShultz How am I supposed to know if you don't explain exactly how it doesn't work and what code you are using? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sry, I'm just trying to add my code when openLightbox function is called from react-photo-gallery component.Whit your code, I click on the img, lightbox is opened but I don't get console.log

Comment: @MarkuzShultz That is not enough of an explanation, did you read the links I posted in my comment? Don't add this information as a comment, add it to your question. Every question should have the code you used, expected behavior, actual behavior and any error messages.

Comment: @MarkuzShultz You must have not read the links I posted, because the question does not have the information I mentioned.